# Save the text-index encoding mapping

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So I am able to train a text classifier with Keras and I can save the model too. My question is when I load the model for predicting unknown texts, I have to encode my input text same way as it was encoded during the training process. How am I able to save the mapping during the training part and reload it when I make the prediction?

This is the code I am using to map words to indexes in training. I use VocabularyProcessor from tensorflow.

```
processor = learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(1000)
x = np.array(list(processor.fit_transform(x_raw)))
y = np.array(y_raw)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out:

```
processor.save(...)
```

and

```
learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor.restore(...)
```